# MSSQL procedure not returning anything via php query

Tags: php, sql-server, yii2

[image: SQL managment studio]

As you can see above stored procedure works correctly on SQL Managment Studio. It returns single value which is later needed. However using Yii2 and PHP I cannot get anything out of this call.
My php code is as follows:

```
$sql     = '{ CALL dbo.UA_Zaloguj (:login, :pass, :LoginMethode, :LoginResult)}';
$command = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql);
$command->bindParam(':login', $this->login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$command->bindParam(':pass', $this->pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$command->bindParam(':LoginMethode', $this->LoginMethode, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$command->bindParam(':LoginResult', $this->LoginResult, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result = $command->execute();
$this->result = $result;
```

The result is always "-1" but should be 0. What am I doing wrong? I cannot fetch the result at all:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting your `ATTR_ERRMODE` to `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`? Otherwise the database will just eat syntax errors. Do it by calling `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: If you want data returned from a stored procedure you should use an OUTPUT parameter or have the procedure return a result set. The RETURN_VALUE is used to indicate a status of the execution, not to return a value.

Answer (score 0):

`$result` tells you if the execution was successful. If you want data, you need to fetch them.

Comment: The execution was successful, it's logged in db, i just cannot fetch the result on PHP side. I tried using queryAll(), queryScalar() and it says:Error : PDOException: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields.

Comment: Then this is a SQL server problem. It expects a field and none is given.